# How to pass file byte array from Java to .Net API and restore byte array to file

Tags: java, c#, .net, rest

I need to pass the file from Java program to .NET api as Byte Array and restore that file through that .Net API.

I have tried to convert to string and pass and as mentioned below but not working.

Java client code:

```
private String getBytesFromFiles(String path){

    try{
      logger.info("Accessing the document====> "+path);


    File file = new File(path);
      InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
      byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
      inputStream.read(bytes);
      logger.info("Byte array converted to String");
      String res = new String(bytes);
    return res;
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.info("Error at reading the document====> "+e);
        //throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

.Net api code:

```
public string  UploadToDBMultiClaims(string strDept, string strPolicyNo1, string strPolicyNo2, List<string> lstClaimNo, string strDocumentName,
        string strFileDate, string strRemark, string strCurrentUser, String btBinaryBuffer){

    byte[] bytes = new byte[btBinaryBuffer.Length * sizeof(char)];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(btBinaryBuffer.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    string strDocID = "xyz"
    string path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"].ToString() + DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + @"\";
    string fileName = path + strDocID + ".pdf";
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, bytes);

    return "1";
}
```

Comment: have you try to compare the bytes from java and c#? is it identical?

Comment: `bytes.toString()` does not return what you think it does. Debug it and look at the return value.

Comment: I also recommend to encode in Base64. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html or transmit as byte[] directly.

Comment: For the .Net Code, I recommend using [`System.IO.Path.Combine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) for building paths.

Comment: Hi @Fildor. i tried using the String res = new String(bytes); also. I will try to use Base64. Also i think i dont need Combine.

Comment: Yes, you don't _need_ it, it just makes your life easier and it is less error prone.